# JQGrid - grid shows but data not loading

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Please help. i have search the old questions but cannot find the related solution.

Click on the button the grid shows but no data loads.

my web reponse:

```
{"d":"{"totalpages":2,"currpage":1,"totalrecords":15,"rows":[{"id":"110","cell":["110","perform action 1"]},{"id":"112","cell":["112","perform action 2"]},...]}"}
```

my JQuery code:

```
    $("#b4").click(function () {doAjax4();});

   function doAjax4() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false, cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebAction.aspx/GetDataTable",
            data: "{}",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#mygrid1").jqGrid({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    colNames: ['runid', 'action'],
                    colModel: [{ name: 'runid', index: 'runid' }, { name: 'action', index: 'action' }],
                    jsonReader: {
                        root: "rows",
                        page: "currpage",
                        total: "totalpages",
                        records: "totalrecords",
                        id: "id",
                        cell: "cell",
                        repeatitems: true
                    },
                    loadonce: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    rowList: [5, 10, 50],
                    caption: "Action Table",
                    height: 'auto',
                    //pager: '#pager',
                    emptyrecords: 'No data for the applied filter'
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, type, exception) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see many problems in your code:

- The type of the value in `d` property of the server response is **string**. So I suppose that you made typical beginner error in the web service `GetDataTable`: you included unneeded conversion to JSON directly in your code. The correct would be just return the **object** from `GetDataTable` instead of the **string**.
- you use `datatype: "json"` parameter in `$.ajax`, but you should use `dataType: "json"` instead. The name of close option in jqGrid is `datatype`, but the name in `$.ajax` is `dataType`.
- you use unneeded parameter `async: false` which I would recommend to remove.
- you call `doAjax4` inside on `click` handler. The function `doAjax4` creates the grid inside of `success` handler by executing the code `$("#mygrid1").jqGrid({`...});`. It's important to understand, that jqGrid convert initial empty table (``) to relatively complex structure of divs and tables. Thus **you can't create the same grid more as once**. The second coll will be just ignored. To fix the problem you should  include the test whether the grid is already created of not and use`$("#mygrid1").trigger("reloadGrid");`instead of`$("#mygrid1").jqGrid({`...});`. Another way to fix the problem would be including the call of `GridUnload` method *before* `$("#mygrid1").jqGrid({`...});`. It will destroy existing grid if it is exist.
- The options of jqGrid contains `dataType: "json"` parameter instead of `datatype: "json"`, so jqGrid used default option `datatype: "xml"`, which is probably not what you want. In the same way you use unknown option `type: "POST"` which exist in `$.ajax`, but which not exist in jqGrid. You should fix the option name from `type` to `mtype`. If you want that jqGrid make HTTP POST request then you should specify `url` parameter (for example `url: "WebAction.aspx/GetDataTable"`)
- the `data` returned in the first Ajax call will be just ignored. If you want that jqGrid uses `data` which you downloaded before then you should use for example `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: data.d`. It would corresponds your current format of data.

Comment: thank you for quick response & detailed answer.

**Changes done -  it works using jsonstring BUT i want to use datatype: "json" & jsonReader. Is it possible or is the approach wrong**  <br />

Corrections:

1. now returning GetDataTable object

2. typo corrected to dataType: "json"

3. removed async: false

4. in success, before $("#mygrid1").jqGrid({...}); added $("#mygrid1").trigger('reloadGrid'); 

5. jqgrid option (a)typo corrected to datatype: "json". (b)typo corrected to mtype. (c)added url: "WebAction.aspx/GetDataTable"

6. set datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: data.d.

Comment: @BipoK: You are welcome! You can remove outer `$.ajax` and use jqGrid with options `datatype: "json", mtype: "POST", url: "WebAction.aspx/GetDataTable"`. You need only change `jsonReader` to use `d.` prefix in all top elements: `jsonReader: { page: "d.currpage", total: "d.totalpages", records: "d.totalrecords", root: "d.rows" }`

Comment: Thank you again. Your responses here and in the many other SO's have been always helpful. Your answers provided the solution. I also had to add 2 additional options. Is this usage correct? options added are [1] `ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}` and [2] `serializeGridData: function (postdata) {return null;}`

Comment: @BipoK: You are welcome! The other options are correct too.